# Weird values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, range

I have a dataframe, df, which contains a features, "Lower Bound", "Upper Bound", and "Step Size".

"Upper Bound" contains 5 unique values, eg:

```
In [1]
df['Upper Bound'].unique()

Out [1]
array([ 0.3 ,  0.  ,  0.2 ,  0.1 ,  0.15])
```

Yet, when I access a specific location within the df, the actual value is different.   eg:

```
In [2]
df.iloc[1]['Upper Bound']

Out [2]
0.29999999999999999
```

This problem is littered throughout the df.  For example, I am trying to generate a list ("assets") of these arrays, with each array representing the range of values from "Lower Bound" to "Upper Bound" by "Step Size."

```
In[3]
assets = []
for i in range(0, len(df['Lower Bound'])-1):
    lst = (np.arange(df.iloc[i]['Lower Bound'],df.iloc[i]['Upper Bound']+0.01,df.iloc[i]['Step Size']))
    assets.append(lst.tolist())
```

The first row of the df is [0.1,0.3,0.1].  Yet the result of the operation above is:

```
Out[3]
[[0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004],
...
```

What gives?

Comment: This is due to floating point precision and the way that the output is formatted for display if you 're trying to perform some kind of equality operation then you should use `np.isclose` to avoid ambiguities

Comment: @EdChum Thanks.   I am trying to perform an equality operation.  eg, trying to select only permuations of the above which sum to 1:                [item for item in itertools.product(*assets) if sum(item) ==1].  How can I use np.isclose in this case?

Comment: add this `if np.isclose(sum(item),1).any()` should work

Comment: @EdChum - Thanks, will do!

Comment: @GPB http://0.30000000000000004.com/